# Incredibuild helper machines can not assigning to build process, why?

Tags: incredibuild

I got only a short warning during build in VS2010

the helper process was unable to initialize due to an unknown error
We use incredibuild 5.0 on Windows 7 and windows 10 helper machines. The coordinator is running under Win10.

Also on the warning window there was an line about .net framework is not compatible. On every machine 4.0 and 4.6.1 .net framework has installed, so no sense... but somehow the only one helper could assign to build which is running windows 7. Any idea what should I try? 
[coordinator window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTR27.jpg)

[warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJ3Fr.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 was release long after IncrediBuild version 5.0
Once Windows 10 was released, a new version of IncrediBuild was which certifies the Win10 OS. Once you'll upgrade to the latest IncrediBuild version (which currently certifies the latest Windows updates), your problem will go away :)

Disclaimer: the writer of this message works at IncrediBuild.